# The first then for my promise returns a promise even though the rejected method has no return function in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, es6-promise

In the code below, the first .then() chained to the addTwo function calls the reject method because I'm checking if type of a and b are "choco", which is impossible.

I expected the output to stop at "we have an error boss" without continuing since the reject method, unlike the resolve method, does not have a "return addTwo" statement.

But the output reveals that the code continues on to the next then call, and the output is "answer of second addition : undefined". How come the code doesn't just stop at the first then call, since the reject method doesn't return a Promise?

```js
var addTwo = (a, b) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
        if(typeof a === choco && typeof b === choco){
            resolve(a + b)
        }else{
            reject("a or b or both were not numbers")
        }
    })
}


addTwo(5, 6).then((res) => {
    console.log("Answer of addition: " + res)
    return addTwo(res, 100)
}, (err) => {
    console.log("We have an error boss: " + err)
}).then((res) => {
    console.log("Answer of second addition: " + res)
}, (err) => {
    console.log("We have an error boss: " + err)
})
```

Comment: Passing a second argument to `a.then(...)` means: *"if `a` is rejected, call that function and return a (successfully) resolved promise if no error is thrown"*. So it's working exactly as designed. If that's not the behavior you want, then you shouldn't pass a second argument to `.then`.

Comment: *"How come the code doesn't just stop at the first then call, since the reject method doesn't return a Promise?"*  You mean `reject`? Neither `resolve` nor `reject` returns a promise. `new Promise` and `.then` *always* return a promise. A promise can be in three different states: "pending", if neither `resolve` nor `reject` have been called, "fulfilled" if `resolve` was called or "rejected" if `reject` was called. The functions you register via `.then` are called when the promise enters a specific state. What happens in these functions determines the state of the promise returned by `.then`.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code, in order for it to work as you intended you need to write it like this:

```
    var addTwo = (a, b) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
        if(typeof a === choco && typeof b === choco){
            resolve(a + b)
        }else{
            reject("a or b or both were not numbers")
        }
    })
}


addTwo(5, 6).then((res) => {
    console.log("Answer of addition: " + res);
    return addTwo(res, 100);
}, (err) => {
    console.log("We have an error boss: " + err);
    throw err;
}).then((res) => {
    res.then(res2) => {
        console.log("Answer of second addition: " + res2);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("We have an error boss: " + err);
        throw err;
}})
```

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complex (and last `throw err` is not propagated properly to the outer promise chain).

Answer (score 0):

just have a common catch. I've updated your code.

```
addTwo(5, 6).then((res) => {
    console.log("Answer of addition: " + res)
    return addTwo(res, 100);
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log("Answer of second addition: " + res)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("We have an error boss: " + err)
})
```

Comment: addTwo returns a promise so you need to chain it

Comment: When `addTwo(res, 100)` is called it'll go to the next then. It's Chained only just that if error occurs there is a common catch. Try running it once on your local for both cases the correct one as well as the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Think of promise chains as having two chains - fulfilled and rejected

Also, you know that .then takes two arguments `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` - if either one of `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` is not a function, it is ignored

`.catch(fn)` is just `.then(null, fn)`

In each of the functions executed by `.then` (either onFulfilled or onRejected), if an error is thrown, then the next `.then`'s `onRejected` will be called next - otherwise the `onFulfilled` will be called next

If any of the arguments to `.then` are not a function, .then ignores them - in the case of onFulfilled not being a function, .then will return a resolved Promise that takes on the fulfilled (resolved) value - and in the case of onRejected not being a function, .then will return a rejected Promise that takes on the rejected value

Your code is literally (just showing the return values, ignoring console.logs)

```
addTwo(5, 6)
.then(res => addTwo(res, 100), err => undefined)
.then(res => undefined, err => undefined);
```

since the first `onRejected` function returns `undefined`, the second `.then(res=>` will be called

As proposed in another answer, you want a single .catch in this case

so

```
    addTwo(5, 6)
   .then((res) => {
        console.log("Answer of addition: " + res)
        return addTwo(res, 100)
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("Answer of second addition: " + res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("We have an error boss: " + err)
    });
```

Which is - without the console.logs

```
addTwo(5, 6)
.then(res => addTwo(res, 100), null)
.then(res => undefined, null)
.then(null, err => undefined);
```

since the first and second .then have null for `onRejected`, i.e. not a function, the "error" flows down the rejected chain until a function is "found"

Answer (score 0):

With a functional style and some helpers, you can factor this problem in a straightforward, highly readable way:

```
import { curry } from 'crocks/helpers/curry'

// async functions always return promises
const addPromise = curry(async (a, b) => {
  if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') {
    throw new Error("a or b or both were not numbers")
  } else {
    return a + b
  }
})

const trace = tag => x => console.log(tag, x) || x

const handleError = err => console.log(`We have an error boss: ${err}`)

addPromise(5, 6)
  .then(trace('Answer from First Addition'))
  .then(addPromise(100))
  .then(trace('Answer from Second Addition'))
  .catch(handleError)
```